# How to update a label when clicking a button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, button

So I'm trying to figure out how to update a specific element in the cshtml files such as a label for example.

So the label is currently  `<p>File ready for upload</p>` and when I click on a button, I want it to change to `<p>Files must be a <b>.jpeg</b> <b>.jpg</b> <b>.png</b> <b>.bmp</b> file format.</p>`

I have already have the logic working for uploading and only allowing those file formats, I just want to alert the user that they need it by changing the label I have said above. I know it would be in my `catch (exception)` since I'm using a `try catch`statement.

My Code:
Controller: **FileSharings.cs**

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Description,FileName,FileType,FileSize,Author,DateUploaded")] FileSharing fileSharing)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files.Get(0);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/"), fileName);
        var allowedExtensions = new string[] { ".jpeg", ".png", ".jpg", ".bmp" };
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        try
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && (ModelState.IsValid) && (allowedExtensions.Contains(extension)))
            {
                file.SaveAs(filePath);
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                fileSharing.FileType = fileInfo.Extension.Remove(0, 1).ToLower();
                fileSharing.DateUploaded = DateTime.Now;
                fileSharing.FileName = fileName;
                fileSharing.FileSize = fileInfo.Length.ToString();
                fileSharing.Author = User.Identity.Name;
                db.FileSharing.Add(fileSharing);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        return View(fileSharing);
    }
```

Comment: you should use js for this in general. But if you show your View we can be more specific

Comment: Easiest to just add a `ModelState` error and return the view (and have it displayed in `ValidationMessageFor()`, but if you want the formatted html you will need to add it to `ViewBag` or a model property and use `@Html.Raw()` in the view

Comment: And it should not be in your `catch` block - you will never throw an exception because the `if` statement is never entered if your files types are not valid

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem has now been solved. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.MyMessageToUsers = "Files must be a <b>.jpeg</b> <b>.jpg</b> <b>.png</b> <b>.bmp</b> file format";;

    return View();
}
```

CSHTML.cs

```
@ViewBag.MyMessageToUsers
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery Solution**

```
  // get file name
    var filename = $("#file_input").val();

    // get extension
    var ext = filename.replace(/^.*\./, '');

   // Validate
   if($.inArray( ext, [ ".jpeg", ".png", ".jpg", ".bmp" ] ) == -1)
        $("#label_error").html("file extension not matched");
```